# Stored Procedures for every little query vs. hard coded sql queries

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a .NET application and was wondering... should I really write a stored procedure for every query I have, or is there some role of thumb here?

I know the benefits of writing SPs (like security, not having to recompile code to change a query, query compilation).

But I find myself many times in situations where I just need a simple select or delete operation against my DB (really really simple stuff - with not parameters) - so what do you think is better - writing a stored procedure for each and every query or having some queries hard coded? I had some projects where I found myself with a great deal of stored procedures just because of that...

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

There are a few options cited for stored procedures:

- performance: this hasn't been true for ages - these days sprocs and parameterized raw commands share the exact same cache
- "the dba can change it if needed" - if the dba changes code without it going through a proper deploy process, I will more than shout at them - and if your c# is harder to deploy than 3 clicks: fix that
- security: this one actually does have some merit, but only in some very limited scenarios like banks; and note - the point here is that the calling account sometimes doesn't have **any** access to the raw tables: just sprocs. Most of us don't work in this environment

Personally, I rarely use sprocs. Raw SQL is much more flexible - and sensible c# code can write appropriate SQL dynamically. You can do that inside SQL too, but it isn't a good fit. You also get to use tools like ORMs. More importantly, it **avoids a huge deployment problem**: the chicken and egg sproc change. If the sproc change is major, you can't deploy the sproc without breaking the callers, and you can't update the callers without updating the sproc. And you have multiple servers calling a single central db. This means that you need to carefully coordinate changes such that both ends are happy. If the query is in the c# this simply isn't a problem: as you update each individual server, it is *by definition* using the version of the query it expects.

Basically, I'm a huge fan of direct parameterized SQL these days.

Comment: Can you provide any links or documentation explaining how "sprocs and parameterized raw commands share the exact same cache"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell (@Marc Gravell) (or anyone else) - does this still stand 10 years later - the arguments still make sense to me, but wonder if anyone has any lessons learned resources?

Comment: @DavidFaivre funnily enough I was literally writing about this last night (I'm writing the official book for Dapper) - mostly it all stands *and then some*, however there is a small caveat in environments that require ad-hoc statements to be "prepared" (for example, on Postgresql). That does add a nominal extra latency fee, although that is cached at the provider layer, so as long as you're using parameterized queries: is amortized. Stored procs can sort of skip that a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you make use of stored procedures and there is a change made to the input parameters or the return result, it will anyway impact your c# code, so the argument that it doesn't impact your code is not true. Also people who opts for stored procedures, ends up implementing business rules/logic in the database, which makes it difficult to determine impact analysis for changes, debugging, traceability etc.

I use stored procedures in the case where there is complicated massaging of data to present it to the consumer (no business logic). It might even be better to make use of Views for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For me it would depend on how you plan on accessing the data and what your security concerns are.

If you are going to be using a data adapter of some sort and you don't need to worry about security then I would say go ahead and write the sql queries in your code.  If you are worried about sql injection attacks then stored procedures are probably a better bet.

On the other hand if you are going to be accessing the data using the Entity Framework then stored procedures probably are not the best way to go, especially if you are planning on using a code first approach.  Using Linq to write your queries is fairly easy and Microsoft does a decent job of translating the code to sql.

That said, if you are going to use EF and map the data points then you can write and assign a stored procedure for each of the crud operations in the data mapping, just so you don't have to use Microsoft's sql for the operation and in case you want to do something extra on the back end during the operation.

Answer (score -1):

I think writing a stored procedure would be a good idea since if say suppose you have to make some changes or add few more queries in future to your existing query then you can directly change the stored procedure. You dont have to change the C# code and build your dll. It would be much easier to change the logic in stored procedure without affecting the C# code.

Also it is stored procedures are **MORE** maintainable because you dont have to recompile you C# code whenever you are doing some changes in SQL

You may also like to check [Stored Procedures vs. Ad-Hoc SQL](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/05/stored-procedures-vs-ad-hoc-sql.html) and [Who Needs Stored Procedures, Anyways?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html) by Jeff Attwood

Comment: I disagree with the point that SP are more **maintainable** because the changes do not require c# compilation. It is indeed easier to make changes in SPs because it does not need compilation, but then again it can easily break things as well if not done correctly.

Comment: It's very bad advice to favour stored procedures because they're easy to update. If you're changing a sproc, then the c# should be retested anyway, which will very probably mean being recompiled. As Marc states in his answer, there are some edge cases for the recommended use of sprocs, but being easy is definitely not one of them.

Answer (score -1):

I use to group CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operation in the same stored procedure.

The trick consists in adding a @operation parameter, and make other optional as needed.

As an example:

```
EXEC sp_myTable_crud @operation='C',
                     @id=123, 
                     @name='mynamewithtypo', 
                     @firstname='my first name', 
                     @birthdate='1999-01-01'

EXEC sp_myTable_crud @operation='U',
                     @id=123, 
                     @name='myname', 

EXEC sp_myTable_crud @operation='R', @id = 123

EXEC sp_myTable_crud @operation='D', @id = 123
```

This reduce drastically the amount or stored procedure used I have for those trivial four operations on a single table.